# GlassFish multiple customer application architecture

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture, glassfish

I'm trying to manage this situation

Every customer will have a different appplication running on the server (cause customization, version ecc..).

We can't install a different application server to every customer.

The customer will have installed a datalogging service that will send data (when requested) to the application running on the glassfish server.

I'm new to web app and i'd like to know if a solution like this can be done.

look the diagram to understand better.

1) [This is needed to avoid a different connection address for each customer service]

Customer service will connect to Service Manager.
   Service manager will tell Customer service the address of its corrisponding
   application on glassfish.

2) [This is needed to avoid a different connection address for each customer browser]

Customer will connect to a generic Login page that will redirect him to the right application connected to his server

[image]

The questions are:

1) is possible to deploy runtime an application from Service Manager when an Customer service connect?

2) is possible to redirect from an application on the server to another one?

Thanks a lot for your time and your help

Answer (score 0):

When the Glassfish server is running, you can deploy a new application via `asadmin deploy` command (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/ghgjj/index.html). You can save your application data (explored war) anywhere and deploy the app to this location (you can use different directories for the users).

Based on this logic the Service Manager has the information which application the user requests and can send the redirect info in the answer.